# Problemas ao excluir determinado elemento de uma lista dentro de outra lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Estou com um problema ao remover um elemento, tenho uma função que é responsável para deletar o elemento dentro de  listas duplamente encadeadas.

***Como funciona?***

Na função principal chama-se o nome de um elemento(filme) na qual deve-se remover. Esse elemento está alocado em uma lista de atores (existe uma lista de filmes para atores)  e existe uma lista de filmes (com uma lista de atores que fazem parte).

***O que preciso fazer?***

Necessito deletar esse elemento da lista de filmes que está contida na lista de atores e se o ator possuir apenas esse filme que está sendo removido é necessário remover também o ator na lista geral de atores.

***O que fiz até agora? (resumidamente a parte principal que está com problema)***

```
.
.
.
typedef struct filme{
    char nome[P];
    char ano[14];
    struct duplaAt *listaAtores;
    struct duplaDir *listaDiretores;
    struct filme *next;
    struct filme *prev;
}filme;

typedef struct Ator{
    char nome[P];
    struct duplaFilm *listaFilmes;
    struct Ator *next;
    struct Ator *prev;
}ator;
typedef struct duplaAt{
    struct Ator *at;
    struct duplaAt *next;
    struct duplaAt *prev;
}duplaAt;
typedef struct duplaFilm{
    struct filme *fil;
    struct duplaFilm *next;
    struct duplaFilm *prev;
}duplaFilm;
void excluirAtRef(char auxInsert[P], struct Ator ** inicioAtores,struct Ator ** fimAtores)
{
    printf("\n TO AQUI! 1");
    struct Ator * atorHead=*inicioAtores;
    struct duplaFilm *refFilme;
    int band;
        while(atorHead!=NULL)
             {
                band=1;
                refFilme=atorHead->listaFilmes;
                while(refFilme!=NULL)
                 {
                    if(strcmp(refFilme->fil->nome,auxInsert)==0)
                 {
                    //flag
                      if(refFilme->prev==NULL && refFilme->next==NULL)
                      {
                       printf("\n TO AQUI! 2 :%s",atorHead->nome);
                       free(refFilme);
                        band=0; 
                      }
                       else if(refFilme->prev==NULL && refFilme->next!=NULL)
                      {

                       refFilme->next->prev=NULL;
                       free(refFilme);
                    printf("\n TO AQUI! 3: %s",atorHead->nome);

                      }
                else if(refFilme->prev!=NULL && refFilme->next!=NULL)
                 {
                     refFilme->prev->next = refFilme->next;
                    refFilme->next->prev = refFilme->prev;
                    free(refFilme);
                printf("\n TO AQUI! 4");

                 }
                else if(refFilme->prev!=NULL && refFilme->next==NULL)
                 {
                    refFilme->prev->next = NULL;

                    free(refFilme);
                    printf("\n TO AQUI! 5");
                 }



                 }
                    refFilme=refFilme->next;
                 }



                if(band==0)
                 {
                 if(atorHead->prev==NULL && atorHead->next==NULL)
                 {
                    *inicioAtores=NULL;
                    *fimAtores=NULL;
                    free(atorHead);
                    printf("\n ATOR TO AQUI!");
                 }
                else if(atorHead->prev==NULL && atorHead->next!=NULL)
                 {
                    atorHead->next->prev = NULL;
                    *inicioAtores = atorHead->next;

                    free(atorHead);
                    printf("\n ATOR TO AQUI! 2");
                 }
                else if(atorHead->prev!=NULL && atorHead->next!=NULL)
                 {
                    atorHead->prev->next = atorHead->next;
                    atorHead->next->prev = atorHead->prev;
                    free(atorHead); 
                    printf("\n ATOR TO AQUI! 3");
                 }
                else if(atorHead->prev!=NULL && atorHead->next==NULL)
                 {
                    atorHead->prev->next = NULL;
                    *fimAtores= atorHead->prev;

                    free(atorHead);
                    printf("\n ATOR TO AQUI! 4");
                 }

                 }

                atorHead=atorHead->next;
             }  

}
```

***Qual é o problema?***

Ao remover o ultimo elemento da lista de filmes nos atores, ele está removendo o ator. (E isso teoricamente não deveria estar acontecendo pois o flag band só está sendo 0 quando o filme for único na lista).